# Java Socket spam causing Too Many Open Files

Tags: java, sockets, spam

I'm running a socket server for a game Server and someone is spamming my server port to cause a Too many open files error. When this happens, my application becomes unable to open new connections.

```
    //Opens a new connection
    @Override
        public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) {
        FilePrinter.print(FilePrinter.SESSION, "IoSession with " + session.getRemoteAddress() + " opened on " + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()), false);

        byte key[] = {BLLABLALBALBALBLALBALBLABLALBALBLALBALBLA};
        byte ivRecv[] = {BLA BLA BLA};
        byte ivSend[] = {BLA BLA BLA};
        ivRecv[3] = (byte) (Math.random() * 255);
        ivSend[3] = (byte) (Math.random() * 255);
        MapleAESOFB sendCypher = new MapleAESOFB(key, ivSend, (short) (0xFFFF - ServerConstants.VERSION));
        MapleAESOFB recvCypher = new MapleAESOFB(key, ivRecv, (short) ServerConstants.VERSION);
        MapleClient client = new MapleClient(sendCypher, recvCypher, session);
        client.setWorld(world);
        client.setChannel(channel);
        session.write(MaplePacketCreator.getHello(ServerConstants.VERSION, ivSend, ivRecv));
        session.setAttribute(MapleClient.CLIENT_KEY, client);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
        MapleClient client = (MapleClient) session.getAttribute(MapleClient.CLIENT_KEY);
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                boolean inCashShop = false;
                if (client.getPlayer() != null) {
                    inCashShop = client.getPlayer().getCashShop().isOpened();                  
                }
                client.disconnect(false, inCashShop);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                FilePrinter.printError(FilePrinter.ACCOUNT_STUCK, t);
            } finally {
                session.close();
                session.removeAttribute(MapleClient.CLIENT_KEY);
                //client.empty();
            }
        }
        super.sessionClosed(session);
    }
```

I already tried blocking more than 5 connections using iptables but it doesn't work. My server is unable to create new connections when a single ip open a thousand fake connections.

This server is a open source game server. You can see the full code here: http://trac.assembla.com/MoopleDEV/browser
The path to this file I posted is: src/net/MapleServerHandler.java

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated

Comment: Can you print the IP address of the spammer, and verify that it is using the same one each time?

Comment: I suggest you take another look at iptables.  Your firewall is the place where you should be addressing such a problem.

Comment: To handle such an issue on the Java side would require you to accept, check, and close bogus connections faster than the attacker creates them.  That's a losing battle.  Even if you managed to keep up with the attacker's current connection rate, all he needs to do to overcome you is add more machines to the attack.  Indeed, if he's serious, he may be able to overwhelm your network stack, not just your application.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson This spam comes from a single IP. I know I can block his IP, but he still can change his IP and launch another spam attack

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know what else I can do with iptables. I thought this rule blocking more than 5 connections would work, but he's still able to cause the error.

Comment: What rule? You need to make the rule work. Period.